# error model referenced in template is not defined

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I am new bee trying baby steps with backbone and underscore, stuck with this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined .

Please advice me what is the problem.

here is my html  it has all the  js and template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>To-do App in Backbone.js</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- ========= -->
<!-- Your HTML -->
<!-- ========= -->

<div  id="page">
    <div id="content"/>
</div>


<!-- ========= -->
<!-- Libraries -->
<!-- ========= -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/template" id="template1">
    <div>

        My modal value =<%= data  %>

    </div>
</script>

<!-- =============== -->
<!-- Javascript code -->
<!-- =============== -->
<script type="text/javascript">

    var HomeModel=Backbone.Model.extend({
                data :'some dummy value loaded from server'
    });

    var HomeView=Backbone.View.extend({
             render:function(){
                 var template = _.template($('#template1').html());
                 $('#content').html(template(new  HomeModel().toJSON()));
             }
     });

    var HomeViewIns= new HomeView();
    HomeViewIns.render();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you say `_.template($('#template1').html())`, [`_.template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template) will convert the template text to a JavaScript function, if you look at that function's source using its `source` property, you'll see something like this (slightly cleaned up):

```
function(obj){
    //...
    with(obj||{}){
        __p += ... ((__t=( data  )) ...
    }
    return __p;
}
```

and there's the reference to `data` that is causing your error. The template function uses [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) to get JavaScript to look for variables (such as `data`) as properties of the `obj` object that you're passing to the template function.

Your `ReferenceError` is telling you that there is no `data` attribute in `new  HomeModel().toJSON()`. Why isn't it there? It isn't there because Backbone models return *attributes* when you call `toJSON` on them and attributes aren't the same as *properties*. You're defining your `HomeModel` to have a `data` *property*:

```
var HomeModel=Backbone.Model.extend({
    data :'some dummy value loaded from server'
});
```

but no attributes. That means that `toJSON` will give you an empty object (i.e. `{}`) and there's no `data` in an empty object.

If you want your model to have a `data` *attribute* then try adding a [`defaults`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults) to it instead:

```
var HomeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        data: 'some dummy value loaded from server'
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/PQN63/

Comment: Aw, you beat me by secs :) Yours is a far better answer, more illustrative!

Comment: what is difference attributes and properties when to use attribute vs property for storing my objext state?  tried google did not find , please help

Comment: Backbone knows about *attributes* and stores them in the model's `attributes` property, *properties* are plain old JavaScript things (like your original `data`) that Backbone generally doesn't know about. Anything you want Backbone to know about would be an attribute, anything that Backbone doesn't need to know about would be a property.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `data` isn't considered an attribute of your model, but a property of the model's instance.

When defining default values for your attributes, you have to do it using the `defaults` property in Backbone models:

```
defaults : {
    attributeName : defaultValue
}
```

When you instantiate a model, Backbone will get the object you pass in the constructor as parameters and the ones in the `defaults` object to construct your model's attributes.

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rx54q/).